# TEmbeddedWB is still loading page and cant be stopped

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tembeddedwb

I was searching here on SO, but without success or any acceptable answer.

I have bigger application, which is using TEmbeddedWB. Lets say my code is like this:

```
// here is some other code where I am working with EmbeddedWB1

EmbeddedWB1.Navigate2('http://www.stackoverflow.com');

while EmbeddedWB1.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE do
begin
  EmbeddedWB1.Stop;
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;

EmbeddedWB1.Navigate2('http://www.google.com');
```

And this code is stuck inside that loop.

When debugging, `EmbeddedWB1.ReadyState = READYSTATE_LOADING`.

Could somebody tell me, how to definitelly stop loading of page, and move on to the next navigate?

Thanks a lot.

**PS:** without that loop, it can normally load another page, f.e. google.com. But I really need to have it in `READYSTATE_COMPLETE` before loading another page.

Comment: stop using busy loops please? there is an event called OnDocumentComplete, use that event to load the next page....

Comment: you dont understand, it will never reach OnDocumentComplete, I want to stop loading page, in other words, I dont want to have READYSTATE_LOADING.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exiting the loop because you're specifically telling it not to do so until the `ReadyState` is `READYSTATE_COMPLETE`, and then calling `Stop` so it can never reach that `ReadyState`.

Follow the logic:

- The line I've marked as `{ 1 }` says "Stay in the loop until ReadyState is READYSTATE_COMPLETE".
- The line I've marked as `{ 2 }` says "Stop loading the page", which means `ReadyState` can **never** be `READYSTATE_COMPLETE`

```
    // This line says "Stay in loop until we reach READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    while EmbeddedWB1.ReadyState  READYSTATE_COMPLETE do   { 1 }
    begin
      EmbeddedWB1.Stop; { 2 }
      Application.ProcessMessages;
    end;
```

You're intentionally preventing your loop from exiting.

If you want to actually stop loading the page and exit the loop, put in a counter or timer, and add a condition to the loop to allow you to exit if the condition is met:

```
Counter := 1;
while (Counter < SomeValue) and (EmbeddedWB1.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE) do
begin
  Inc(Counter);
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;

if Counter >= SomeValue then
  EmbeddedWB1.Stop;   // Had to break the loop above before complete. 
                      // trying to load and move on.
```

Comment: I understood your logic, but that was not the problem, just TEmbeddedWB is strange in some way. I recode it all, and now its working. Thanks.